# pfSense DMZ VMware and Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, vmware-esxi, pfsense, dmz, ubuntu-16.04

In a VMware environment I am having connectivity issues (no ping) between the gateway (pfSense DMZ) and Ubuntu server 16.04.1 LTS.

Pfsense is working fine from the LAN subnet 192.168.1.0/24 but not from DMZ subnet 10.10.10.0/24

I think I have configured the firewall side of things correctly (pfsense), but new to VMware so I think I might be missing something within the VMware environment and/or ubuntu server?

Ubuntu server has an IP address 10.10.10.6
pfSense webdmz gateway has an IP address 10.10.10.3

Looking at the topology, on vSwitch2(LAN) I connect a computer on vmnic5 I can get to the internet no problem. But on vSwitch3(WEBDMZ) I am unable to ping either way 10.10.10.6 to gateway 10.10.10.3 and vice versa.

Has someone come across same issue before?

Topology:

[image: topology]

Firewall DMZ config and ubuntu interface:

[image: firewall dmz config and ubuntu interface]

Answer (score 0):

In case someone comes across the same issue.

I solved this by deploying a fresh images of pfsense. Paying particular attention to assigning when configuring the interfaces and vSwitchs in VMware before hand, which I think was the cause of the issue.